# how to debug puppeteer in headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, jasmine, e2e-testing, headless, puppeteer

Does anyone knows how can i debug puppeteer while it runs headless?
I have this E2E Jasmine test which runs fine under non headless mode , but as soon as i run headless , it fails. i'm trying to understand why it fails under headless mode (i'm suspecting it is related to a react render stuff)  , but in order to get some common sense , i must use a debugger.
P.S the documentation implies i should run non headless in order to see whats going on , but thats not helping in my case :/ 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can debug it easily with `DEBUG`.

Example command to run,

```
DEBUG=* node app.js
```

Comment: how would I do this on cloud function?

Comment: Can you share your code snippet or what cloud function you are talking about etc?

Comment: I have created a question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318724/page-goto-freezes-on-cloud-functions-for-some-websites/55356281#55356281

Answer (score 0):

If you need some sort of visual debugging I run an OS project called [browserless](https://github.com/joelgriffith/browserless) that has a built-in debugger. It allows you to (essentially) paste in puppeteer scripts and watch/interact with the output in the browser. It's a little nicer than trying to comb through DEBUG logs since it can be pretty noisy.