# page.goto freezes on Google Cloud Functions for some websites

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, chromium, puppeteer

I am using:

```
Puppeteer version: 1.13.0
Platform / OS version: Google Cloud
Node.js version: 8
```

`await.page.goto("https://somewebsite.com")` freezes when I deploy it on Google Cloud functions.

I receive timeout error.
`Navigation Timeout Exceeded`

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      args: [
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--single-process', // <- this one doesn't works in Windows
      ]
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    try {
      await page.goto('https://somewebsite.com',
                      { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('page.goto ERROR: ', error);
    }
```

I can see it working in different environments:

- AWS
- Locally

It works for all except **Google Cloud Functions**. However, if I try `google.com` it works.

The problem is that the error is not helpful at all, the `page.goto` is just timing out.

**I was wondering if there is a proper way to debug this?**

**Could it be OS issue?**
but then again, AWS and Google cloud are both Linux based?

Comment: Is your Google Cloud project on a payment plan?

Comment: Yes I am using it for several projects. Its on paid plan.

Comment: I suggest you share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) anyway, even if you don't think there's a point to it.  You could still be making a mistake somewhere that just isn't showing up elsewhere.  Without code, we'll never know.

Comment: @DougStevenson I uploaded a snippet of code above.

Comment: I've seen puppeteer work just fine in Cloud Functions using only `--no-sandbox` for launch args, and using goto without `waitUntil`.

Comment: @DougStevenson it works for `google.com` but its not working for few websites.
If its ssl error, it  should be ignored with those flags in args.

Comment: Same problem, the timeout seems totally random on our side (same site sometimes works, sometimes don't, happens with google sites AND random sites).

Comment: @kursus I wonder if there is a way to debug this?
Because page.goto freezes instead of catching the actual error

Comment: Most likely a faulty build was pushed and nothing can be done about it except drawing attention :(

Comment: You can enable verbose logging by setting the environment variable `DEBUG="puppeteer:*"`. Check out [debugging tips](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#debugging-tips) for more information.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf  Thanks! I have no idea how I skipped this.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is an issue with timing in Puppeteer version 1.13.0. Try downgrading to  1.11.0 and it should work fine.

A similar question was answered in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55350592/4037220). It points to [this discussion](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3944).

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. `page.goto` freezes, I am not even able to navigate to the page.

Comment: I had the same issue. I added 4 web pages to load using page.goto method. 3 executed without error, 4th had 30000ms timeout. Then I changed my GCF set up and it executed properly. My GCF is set up like, **Nodejs 8** environment, **Puppeteer 1.11.0** version, Memory allocated **1 GB**, Timeout **300 seconds**. Try this set up and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That's exactly the setup that I have :(  the problem is that only this specific website does not load at all. I guess it has some error (maybe ssl error, really not sure), which is not handled correctly on Google cloud Linux in Chromium, but Its working anywhere else, like AWS, or my local MAC machine

Comment: Can you share the website that you are getting this issue at? I want to try to replicate the issue.

Comment: I am working for Google Cloud Platform Support, but in order to provide further assistance you will have to create a [private issue tracker > For Google Cloud Functions component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491477), that so we could have access to your project and investigate further.